# Can't find specific table row in Rails 6 integration test with assert_select - always finds the header row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm using Rails 6.1.0 with Minitest 5.14.2.

I have a controller `app/controllers/buildings_controller.rb`:

```rb
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @buildings = Building.order(:name)
  end
end
```

and a view `app/views/buildings/index.html.haml`:

```rb
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{scope: 'col'} Name
      %th{scope: 'col'}
  %tbody
    - if @buildings.any?
      - @buildings.each do |building|
        %tr
          %td= building.name
          %td.text-right= link_to(icon('fas', 'pencil-alt', 'Edit'), edit_building_path(building), class: 'btn btn-index-action')
    - else
      %tr
        %td.empty-row{colspan: 2} Nothing to show
```

and a test file `test/buildings/index_test.rb` that includes a test `shows the building name` intended to show that a row exists on the page containing the name of one of the buildings created in the setup:

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class BuildingsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = FactoryBot.create(:user, :staff)
    @buildings = FactoryBot.create_list(:building, 5)
    sign_in(@user)
  end

#...

  test 'shows the building name' do
    get(buildings_path)

    assert_response(:success)
    assert_select('tr', text: @buildings[0].name)
  end

#...

end
```

But the test fails, clearly selecting the header row and failing:

```
# Running:

F

Failure:
BuildingsControllerTest#test_shows_the_building_name [/app/test/integration/buildings/index_test.rb:37]:
<Nakia Kuvalis Institute> expected but was
<Name>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


rails test test/integration/buildings/index_test.rb:33



Finished in 1.835443s, 0.5448 runs/s, 1.0897 assertions/s.
1 runs, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I have tried `assert_select('tr', @buildings[0].name)` and get the same result. Using `assert_match(@buildings[0].name, @response.body)` works but I'm curious why I can't test specifically that a table row exists with given text.

In other projects using RSpec and Capybara, I would have done `expect(page).to have_selector('tr', text: @buildings[0].name)` and I would've expected it to work.

How do I do what I want in a Rails integration test?

Answer (score 0):

rails-dom-testing seems to test the `text` constraint by comparing it to the whole content of the selected element. In my case, there was also an Edit link in the row, which led to the assertion failing. Capybara's matchers, by contrast, automatically wrap the text in a regex. I can't find the line in [rails-dom-testing](https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing) where the text constraint is tested, though, so I can't confirm.

The test output is a bit confusing because the rails-dom-testing gem adds an implicit `:minimum` constraint (hence `Expected 0 to be >= 1.`) and displays the text of the first matched selector (the header row in my case) when the text constraint isn't met (hence `<Janetta Rogahn JD Building> expected but was <Name>..`).

Wrapping the text in a regex works:

```rb
assert_select('tr', /#{@buildings[0].name}/)`
```

And so does testing for a table *cell* with the text:

```rb
assert_select('td', @buildings[0].name)`
```

I hope this saves somebody else some time in future!